# Google API: one authenticated user for all

Tags: ruby, api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I need to read/insert events into a specific calendar, using Google API. All registered users (in my app) can read and insert events into the calendar. I don't have to authenticate each user with OAuth 2.0, because the app will not read the user data - only specific account data.

I'm a professor and all my students can read and insert in my calendar. So, they do not need to login (Google Account) to do it, because it's a single account's data.

Is there a way to set a unique key for the main account?

OAuth2 doesn't makes me sense.

Comment: Are you familiar with Service Accounts?

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount) here. It is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end-user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required. (In non-service-account scenarios, your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.)

The [Calendar API can use the Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#perform-google-apps-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority). For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on behalf of users.

For more information, check these threads:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)
- [How to list Google Calendar Events without User Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117095/how-to-list-google-calendar-events-without-user-authentication)
- [Embed Google Calendar only users logged into my website (not necessarily through Google) can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194135/embed-google-calendar-only-users-logged-into-my-website-not-necessarily-through?rq=1)